# runtimeException in ringdroid on android - how to catch exception

Tags: android, exception, ringdroid

[Ringdroid](https://github.com/mitch000001/ringdroid) is a 3rd party app im using to edit music. My question isn't really about ringdroid.  Ringdroid is crashing on some android devices and i've provided the stack trace below. My question is how can i catch an exception from this third party app when im using startActivity(...) to launch it in android ?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {org.jefferyemanuel.waitingtones/com.ringdroid.RingdroidSelectActivity}: android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2742)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1276)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.
at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.throwIfCursorIsClosed(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:64)
at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.requery(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:133)
at android.database.CursorWrapper.requery(CursorWrapper.java:186)
at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:5157)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5183)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
... 10 more
```